# pjsua: unable to import pjsua python module

Tags: python, sip, osx-mountain-lion, pjsip

I'm getting the below error while trying to import python module pjsua. I have Mac OS 10.8.1 version. I verified the solution provided in http://www.darrensessions.com/?p=292 and the solution seemed to have fixed this issue in MacOS-10.7. Seems like this is broken again for MacOS-10.8. I did not got any errors when compiling the code. Only get the below error when importing PJSUA module.

```
>>> import pjsua
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pjsua.py", line 59, in <module>
    import _pjsua
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pjsua.so, 2): Symbol not found: _AudioOutputUnitStart
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pjsua.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pjsua.so
```

Your help in highly appreciated. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straight-forward solution would be (purely theoretical, haven't tested):

1. Look at http://lists.pjsip.org/pipermail/pjsip_lists.pjsip.org/2011-November/013722.html
2. See, where the patch says:

   ```
   # OS X Lion Support
   if platform.mac_ver()[0].startswith("10.7"):
   extra_link_args += ["-framework", "AudioUnit"]
   ```
3. Change line

   ```
   if platform.mac_ver()[0].startswith("10.7"):
   ```

   to

   ```
   if platform.mac_ver()[0].startswith("10.7") or platform.mac_ver()[0].startswith("10.8"):
   ```
4. Recompile

-- edit --

Ok, I patched it as I suggested and:

```
> python ~/a.py 
a
> cat ~/a.py 
import pjsua

test = "a"
print test
```

Comment: Hi favoretti, I tried the above solution but still getting the error.

Comment: Ok, let me try to patch that for you.

Comment: Did you do `make distclean`, `make dep`, `make`, `make install` and then remake and reinstall python module?

Comment: Once I deleted and redid the process as you suggested that solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error was recently fixed as showed above in PJSIP 2.4 python package:

```
# OS X Lion (10.7.x) or above support
    if version[0] == '10' and int(version[1]) >= 7:
        extra_link_args += ["-framework", "AudioUnit"]
```

The funny thing is that I run in the same error:

```
    macbookproloreto:python admin$ python samples/simplecall.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "samples/simplecall.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pjsua as pj
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pjsua.py", line 59, in <module>
    import _pjsua
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pjsua.so, 2): Symbol not found: _pj_atexit
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pjsua.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pjsua.so
```

not understanding why since the Python setup.py script checking the platform version seems to be fine:

```
>>> import platform
>>> version = platform.mac_ver()[0].split(".")
>>> version
['10', '10', '4']
>>>
```

Comment: Make sure you do a `make && make install`. That import error would occur if you forget the `make` part.