# How to "import pjsua" in python on MAC

Tags: python, pjsua2

Am using python 2.7 and got error like "ImportError: No module named _pjsua" while using "import pjsua". I refered and tried some solution but no luck on those solutions.

[pjsua: unable to import pjsua python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021277/pjsua-unable-to-import-pjsua-python-module)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "pjsua.py", line 59, in 
    import _pjsua
ImportError: No module named _pjsua

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup pjsip for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535729/setup-pjsip-for-python)

Comment: The `_pjsua` module is the low-level C Python extension. If this didn't compile or didn't install correctly, it won't be imported.

Comment: @Kris Roofe i tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535729/setup-pjsip-for-python but no luck